# How might I prove that a line of irrational slope bounded by a "wrap-around" square, must pass through every point on the interior of the square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sticking with two dimensions and the cartesian coordinate system, let's say I start drawing the line $y=x/2$ at the origin, bounded by a box with vertices $(\pm1,\pm1)$. This line would intersect the boundary at $(1,0.5)$ and then would "wrap around" to $(-1, 0.5)$, where it would continue to rise until meeting the boundary at $(0,1)$, wrapping around to $(0,-1)$, where it would rise to $(1, -0.5)$, wrapping to $(-1,-0.5)$ then meeting itself again at the point $(0,0)$. Because this line has a rational slope $1/2$, it must eventually loop back on itself.

[image: Line of slope 1/2 wrapping around on itself]

Is this true for a line with an irrational slope? Further, must a line which does not loop back on itself necessarily hit every point in the interior of the boundary? How might I prove this? I am aware that a space which wraps around on itself like this is analogous to a torus, but I'm not too well-versed in topology. Can this idea be extended to polynomials of any degree so long as they have irrational (just one? all of them?) coefficients?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't see how it can be countably many.

Comment: It doesn't hit only countably many points, you're right. Its path does consist of only countably many line segments, which is enough to show that it doesn't hit every point in the torus ("wrap-around square"). The Kronecker–Weyl theorem shows that the path is dense in the torus, and so we get arbitrary close to every point, but not exactly.

Comment: @GregMartin That should be an answer.

Comment: @GregMartin What does it look like to get arbitrarily close to a point, but never reach it? Don't we use the same idea of arbitrary closeness to define continuity?

Comment: @MatthewSylvester for $A$ to be dense in $B$ means that given any two elements of $B$ there is some element of $A$ between them. A simple examples is that the rationals and the irrationals are dense in the reals. So while not all reals are rational they're "close" to all the irrational numbers in some meaningful sense.

Comment: I don't think CyclotomicField's comment is accurate (consider the even and odd integers) and certainly not in this case where we're talking about subsets of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @MatthewSylvester see my second comment on Ross Millikan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A line with irrational slope will not loop back on itself.  We can rotate the coordinate system so that the line passes through $(0,0)$.  In that case the line is $y=mx$ where we add or subtract $2$s to get the coordinates into the range $[-1,1)$ to plot the point.  There are only countably many lines traversing the square, so only countably many points on the $y$ axis, or any other line with a slope different from $m$ will be on one of them.  This shows most points in the square will not be on any of the lines.  The lines will be dense in the square, so will approach any point arbitrarily closely.  On any line with slope different from $m$ they will be like the rationals in the reals, a countable dense set.

The same idea will work for most polynomials as long as at least one coefficient is real.  I don't know how to prove that the graph for a higher degree polynomial will not have a finite region that it avoids, but that must be a very fragile phenomenon.

Comment: "On any line they will be like the rationals in the reals, a countable dense set" isn't correct—there are plenty of lines disjoint from the image (and others that intersect it in a continuum.

Comment: Since the OP seems to be confused by this (common but) imprecise terminology: by a set "approaching a point arbitrarily closely", we mean that given any point $p$ and any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a point in the image that is within $\varepsilon$ of $p$. That's different fron the notion of continuity, where the inputs to the function must also be approaching a limit, not just the outputs; an example illustrating the difference is the graph of $y=\sin(1/x)$, which approaches arbitrarily close to the origin even though the function $\sin(1/x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: @GregMartin:  both your comments are correct.  I was thinking of a cross section through the lines as being like the rationals, which is the point of any line with a slope different from $m$. I'll update.  Thanks.